# Spring boot - display specific columns from my database (SQL)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I am programming in Spring Tools, with the Spring Boot framework.

I find myself in a situation that has taken me hours and I have not been able to solve. I have a database in MySql WorkBench.

All data is of type String, I use the following in my db:

[image: Data]

I want to create an SQL statement to show only the `state` and `admission_number`.

I make the following sentence:

[image: This is the SQL sentence]

When I run the program and look in the driver for the statement I get the following error:

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
> [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could
> not execute query; SQL [SELECT state, admission_number FROM state];
> nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could
> not execute query] with root cause

I understand that it does not find in the sentence the next column to `state`, it is as if it will ask me for all the columns to be able to make a select:

Error description:
[image: Error description]

In my database The columns are this way, if I add in my sentence the column `admission_date`, it tells me that the column `admission_number` was not found.
[image: Column not found]

Thank you and I hope I've been clear (It's my first time asking)
Code state - model:

```
   import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;



@Entity
@Table(name="state")
public class State {
    
    @Id
    private String state;
    private String slug;
    private String code;
    private String nickname;
    private String website;
    private String admission_date;
    private int admission_number;
    private String capital_city;
    private String capital_url;
    private int population;
    private int population_rank;
    private String constitution_url;
    private String state_flag_url;
    private String state_seal_url;
    private String map_image_url;
    private String landscape_background_url;
    private String skyline_background_url;
    private String twitter_url;
    private String facebook_url;
    
    @OneToOne 
    @JoinColumn(name="gobernador_id") 
    private Gobernador gobernador;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="pais_id")
    private Pais pais;
     
    public State() {
    }
    
    public State(String state, String slug, String code, String nickname, String website, String admission_date,
            int admission_number, String capital_city, String capital_url, int population, int population_rank,
            String constitution_url, String state_flag_url, String state_seal_url, String map_image_url,
            String landscape_background_url, String skyline_background_url, String twitter_url, String facebook_url) {
        super();
        this.state = state;
        this.slug = slug;
        this.code = code;
        this.nickname = nickname;
        this.website = website;
        this.admission_date = admission_date;
        this.admission_number = admission_number;
        this.capital_city = capital_city;
        this.capital_url = capital_url;
        this.population = population;
        this.population_rank = population_rank;
        this.constitution_url = constitution_url;
        this.state_flag_url = state_flag_url;
        this.state_seal_url = state_seal_url;
        this.map_image_url = map_image_url;
        this.landscape_background_url = landscape_background_url;
        this.skyline_background_url = skyline_background_url;
        this.twitter_url = twitter_url;
        this.facebook_url = facebook_url;
    }


    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }


    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }


    public String getSlug() {
        return slug;
    }


    public void setSlug(String slug) {
        this.slug = slug;
    }


    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }


    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }


    public String getNickname() {
        return nickname;
    }


    public void setNickname(String nickname) {
        this.nickname = nickname;
    }


    public String getWebsite() {
        return website;
    }


    public void setWebsite(String website) {
        this.website = website;
    }


    public String getAdmission_date() {
        return admission_date;
    }


    public void setAdmission_date(String admission_date) {
        this.admission_date = admission_date;
    }


    public int getAdmission_number() {
        return admission_number;
    }


    public void setAdmission_number(int admission_number) {
        this.admission_number = admission_number;
    }


    public String getCapital_city() {
        return capital_city;
    }


    public void setCapital_city(String capital_city) {
        this.capital_city = capital_city;
    }


    public String getCapital_url() {
        return capital_url;
    }


    public void setCapital_url(String capital_url) {
        this.capital_url = capital_url;
    }


    public int getPopulation() {
        return population;
    }


    public void setPopulation(int population) {
        this.population = population;
    }


    public int getPopulation_rank() {
        return population_rank;
    }


    public void setPopulation_rank(int population_rank) {
        this.population_rank = population_rank;
    }


    public String getConstitution_url() {
        return constitution_url;
    }


    public void setConstitution_url(String constitution_url) {
        this.constitution_url = constitution_url;
    }


    public String getState_flag_url() {
        return state_flag_url;
    }


    public void setState_flag_url(String state_flag_url) {
        this.state_flag_url = state_flag_url;
    }


    public String getState_seal_url() {
        return state_seal_url;
    }


    public void setState_seal_url(String state_seal_url) {
        this.state_seal_url = state_seal_url;
    }


    public String getMap_image_url() {
        return map_image_url;
    }


    public void setMap_image_url(String map_image_url) {
        this.map_image_url = map_image_url;
    }


    public String getLandscape_background_url() {
        return landscape_background_url;
    }


    public void setLandscape_background_url(String landscape_background_url) {
        this.landscape_background_url = landscape_background_url;
    }


    public String getSkyline_background_url() {
        return skyline_background_url;
    }


    public void setSkyline_background_url(String skyline_background_url) {
        this.skyline_background_url = skyline_background_url;
    }


    public String getTwitter_url() {
        return twitter_url;
    }


    public void setTwitter_url(String twitter_url) {
        this.twitter_url = twitter_url;
    }


    public String getFacebook_url() {
        return facebook_url;
    }


    public void setFacebook_url(String facebook_url) {
        this.facebook_url = facebook_url;
    }
}
```

Code state - controller:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import co.edu.poli.model.State;
import co.edu.poli.repository.StateRepository;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/ap/v1")
public class StateController {
    @Autowired
    private StateRepository stateRepository;

    public StateController() {
        
    }

    //Metodo de post para insertar una fila en la base de datos - POST
    @PostMapping("/postState")
    public State insertstate(@RequestBody State estado) {
        stateRepository.save(estado);
        return estado;
    }
    

    //Metodo de post para insertar una lista en filas en la base de datos -POSTLIST
    @PostMapping("/postListState")
    public String createstateList(@RequestBody List<State> estado) {
        stateRepository.saveAll(estado);
        return "done";
    }
    //Metodo de getAll para mostrar todas las filas de la base de datos -GET ALL
    @GetMapping("/get") //Get All
    public List<State> selectstate(){
        return stateRepository.findAll();           
    }
    //Metodo de getBy para mostrar las filas seleccionadas por estado de la base de datos - GET
    @GetMapping("/get2/{idstate}") //Get by ID
    public State getstateById(@PathVariable String idstate){
        State state = stateRepository.findById(idstate).get();  
        return state;
        
    }
    //Metodo de Delete borrar filas seleccionadas por estado de la base de datos - DELETE
    @DeleteMapping("/delete") //DELETE
    public State deletePais(@RequestParam("idstate") String idState) {
        State state_update = stateRepository.getById(idState);
        stateRepository.delete(state_update);
        return state_update;
    }
    
    //Metodo de actualizar filas seleccionadas por estado de la base de datos. - UPDATE
    @PutMapping("/put/{idstate}")
    public State updatestate(@PathVariable String idstate, @RequestBody State state) {
        State state_update = stateRepository.getById(idstate);
        state_update.setState(state.getState());
        state_update.setSlug(state.getSlug());
        state_update.setCode(state.getCode());
        state_update.setNickname(state.getNickname());
        state_update.setWebsite(state.getWebsite());
        state_update.setAdmission_date(state.getAdmission_date());
        state_update.setAdmission_date(state.getAdmission_date());
        state_update.setCapital_city(state.getCapital_city());
        state_update.setCapital_url(state.getCapital_url());
        state_update.setPopulation_rank(state.getPopulation());
        state_update.setPopulation(state.getPopulation());
        state_update.setConstitution_url(state.getConstitution_url());
        state_update.setState_flag_url(state.getState_flag_url());
        state_update.setState_seal_url(state.getState_seal_url());
        state_update.setLandscape_background_url(state.getLandscape_background_url());
        state_update.setSkyline_background_url(state.getSkyline_background_url());
        state_update.setTwitter_url(state.getTwitter_url());
        state_update.setFacebook_url(state.getFacebook_url());
        stateRepository.save(state_update);
        return state;
    }

    
    @GetMapping("/getDatosEspecial")
     public List<State> getbyspeccial(){
        return stateRepository.findDatos();
    }

}
```

Code state - repository:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import co.edu.poli.model.State;

public interface StateRepository extends JpaRepository<State, String>{
    
    @Query(value="SELECT state, admission_number FROM state", nativeQuery=true)
    List<State> findDatos();
}
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code/errors/data. Instead post the code/errors/data as text in a code block. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot retrieve only some specific columns directly into your entity object.

You have multiple solutions :

1. Retrieve the whole data directly into your entity :

```java
@Query("select s from State")
List<State> findDatos();
```

Which could be simply written using derived method name when using Spring Data :

```java
List<State> findAll();
```

But I guess this is what you are trying to avoid.

2. Retrieve only needed columns into a custom object (you need to create that corresponding bean, with the right constructor)

```java
@Query("select new com.example.CustomState(state, admission_number) from State")
List<CustomState> findDatos();
```

3. Retrieve only needed columns into an interface (you need to create that interface)

```java
@Query("select state, admission_number from State", nativeQuery = true)
List<StateInterface> findDatos();
```

But this will be read only data.

4. Retrieve only needed columns into a custom object (using a native query)

You will have to use `@NamedNativeQuery` and `@SqlResultSetMapping` to map the columns to the custom object.

The first 2 solutions use JPQL, while the last ones use native queries. Pick the one you want according to your needs.

Comment: I'm using my interface:
@Query(value="SELECT state, admission_number FROM state", nativeQuery=true)
 List<State> findDatos();
I'm using my controller:  @GetMapping("/getDatosEspecial")
  public List<State> getbyspeccial(){
  return stateRepository.findDatos();
 }  And I get the error: Column 'admission_date' not found.

Comment: Please provide your interface definition, and make sure all method names match the column names. i.e. if your interface method name is `getAdmissionNumber()`, use an alias in your query : `select state, admission_number as admissionNumber from State`.

Comment: The error persists, everything is in order, I understand that the select seeks that I insert all the columns in the database, if I do not insert it the error will be of type "java.sql.SQLException: Column 'name of the column not typed in the select' not found."

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code for your `State` object.

Comment: OK so `State` is a class, not an interface, you cannot select only some columns into your entity class, you either have to select all data (see point 1. in my answer), or if you really need to select only some columns, use an interface projection or a custom object (point 2. 3. or 4. in my answer).

Comment: Thank you very much, you solved my problem in the best way, thank you for your time and for your dedication

Comment: Thank you very much, your information has been quite useful, but I have a doubt, if I want to show only the selected data when capital_city starts with the fin "a", do you know how I can get it?, that is to say something like this: "SELECT s.state AS state, s.admission_number AS admissionNumber FROM State s WHERE capital_city LIKE a%" But this way does not work as an empty arrangement returns

Comment: You have to put the value inside single quotes : `SELECT s.state AS state, s.admission_number AS admissionNumber FROM State s WHERE capital_city LIKE 'a%'`. If the target is to get the value from a named parameter, you can use `List<State> findDatos(String filter);` and then `SELECT s.state AS state, s.admission_number AS admissionNumber FROM State s WHERE capital_city LIKE :filter%`.

Answer (score 0):

You define an interface and your interface have got two method getAdmissionNumber() and getState().

```
public interface CustomState {

    int getAdmissionNumber();
    String getState();

}
```

---

```
public StateRepository extends JpaRepository<State, String>{
    @Query("select s.state AS state, s.admission_number AS admissionNumber from State s")
    List<CustomState> listAdmissionNumberAndState();

}
```

And thank you @Yann39 I learn second usage now

Have a good day.

Comment: Thank you very much, your information has been quite useful, but I have a doubt, if I want to show only the selected data when capital_city starts with the fin "a", do you know how I can get it?, that is to say something like this:  "SELECT s.state AS state, s.admission_number AS admissionNumber FROM State s WHERE capital_city LIKE a%" But this way does not work as an empty arrangement returns